# Angular Material Dialogue issue - Error: The selector "dialog-result-example-dialog" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am creating a table of items, in which there is a button in each row to delete that item. On clicking delete button, I want a dialogue box to appear which is actually MatDialogueModule from Angular Material. I am getting the dialogue box, but I am getting the error mentioned in the title above.

I have defined @Component and class DialogResultExampleDialog outside the class ListComponent (The one which holds the table). I have also mentioned DialogResultExampleDialog in @NgModule's declarations and bootstrap in app.module.ts

In list.component.ts, outside class ListComponent:

```js
@Component({
  selector:'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example-dialog.html'
)}

export class DialogResultExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

In app.module.ts:

```js
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    ListComponent,
    DialogResultExampleDialog
  ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent, DialogResultExampleDialog]
)}
```

Comment: I think you also need to declare DialogResultExampleDialog as an entryComponent.

Comment: paste the code where you called your method to open mat dialog

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Yes it worked. Thankyou. And it should be removed from `bootstrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add `MatDialogueModule` to the `imports` array in the `app.module.ts`

Also, you don't need `DialogResultExampleDialog` in the `bootstrap`, but it should be in the `entryComponents` array in the `app.module.ts`

Comment: Sorry I did not mention, but I have already added `MatDialogueModule` to the `imports` array in the `app.module.ts`

Comment: @AnuranjanBose can you please create a stackblitz with the problem?

Comment: Hey thankyou, I dropped `DialogResultExampleDialog' inside `entryComponents` and removed it from `bootstrap` and the error's gone!